# Computer Keeps Resetting

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, reset, hp-laptop

Windows 10:
Every time I turn on my computer, everything is gone
1. Wallpaper set back to default
2. Taskbar apps back to default
3. All saved passwords in apps disappear
4. All pictures and most downloads disappear
Only started happening after the recent update. (I updated on the 15th of may)

How to solve this issue?